# Bad request with JSON Payload with Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I implemented an HTTP Client that can send payloads containing base 64 files. For small files I don't have any issues. On the other hand, when i try to send big files over 20Mo, I have error messages. For the application, I would not like to use MultiPart file, if i have the choice.

**Here is my client implementation**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = MappersUtils.objectMapper();
String requestBody = objectMapper
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(request);

HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(url + certificateName))
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(600))
        .build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
       .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
       .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
       .build();

CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> response =
        httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

String result = response.thenApply(HttpResponse::body).get(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
int statusCode = response.thenApply(HttpResponse::statusCode).get(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(statusCode);
return objectMapper.readValue(result, PdfConvertAndSignResponse.class);
```

**On the other side my API is using spring boot and receive an object that is handled.**

```
@PostMapping(
        value = "/convert-and-sign/{certificateName}",
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@Operation(summary = "Convert into PDF/A Level (if it's required) and sign it ")
public ResponseEntity<PdfConvertAndSignResponse> convertAndSign(@RequestBody @Length(max = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1) PdfConvertAndSignRequest request,
                                                                @PathVariable String certificateName) throws PdfException {
    String entryPoint = getEntrypoint(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri());
    LocalDateTime startedAt = LocalDateTime.now(GlobalConstants.ZONE_ID);

    LogDto logDto = LogBuilderUtils.logDtoBuilder(
            request.getHeaderData().getService(),
            PdfConstants.WEBSERVICE,
            entryPoint,
            startedAt,
            HttpVerbs.POST.name());

    CertificateEntity certificateEntity = certificateRepository.findByCertificateName(certificateName);
    if (certificateEntity != null) {
        String pwd = b64ToString(certificateEntity.getPassword());
        PdfConvertAndSignRequestData data = MappersUtils.modelMapper().map(certificateEntity, PdfConvertAndSignRequestData.class);
        data.setPassword(pwd);
        List<PdfConvertAndSignRequestData> toProcess = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PdfConvertAndSignRequestData> currentData = request.getData();
        currentData.forEach(pdfSignRequestData -> {
            data.setPdf(pdfSignRequestData.getPdf());
            toProcess.add(data);
        });
        request.setData(toProcess);
        return doConvertAndSign(request, logDto);
    } else {
        throw new PdfSignRequestException("No certificate found", logDto);
    }
}
```

**Response :**

Here is the response from my client when i call an application deployed in a tomcat server and when i call my webservice when a jar is running:

```
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Failed to read request","instance":"/pdfmanager-ws/v1/convert-and-sign/mycertname"}
400

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because the return value of "fr.dsidiff.pdf.client.model.response.PdfConvertAndSignResponse.getData()" is null
```

**On my deployment server I have a localhost_access_log file with the following content:**

192.168.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2023:14:49:32 +0200] "POST /pdfmanager-ws/v1/convert-and-sign/mycertname HTTP/1.1" 400 161
192.168.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2023:14:49:47 +0200] "POST /pdfmanager-ws/v1/convert-and-sign/mycertname HTTP/1.1" 400 161

At least i know my call is made.

**Configuration in tomcat:**
I updated server.xml configuration file in tomcat

```
<Connector  port="8090" 
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            maxThreads="150" 
            connectionTimeout="-1"
            maxPostSize="109951162777600"
            maxSwallowSize="109951162777600"
            redirectPort="8443" />
```

**In application.properties:**
As i also run my application with embedded tomcat, I have a second app with the following application.properties content :

```
# maximum size of the request body/payload
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# maximum size of entire POST request
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=200MB
```

With this configuration I have the same error response. If i add the folowing configuration:

```
server.http2.enabled=true
```

I now obtain: HTTP Status 413 – Payload Too Large

How can i configure both application to send in json my payload without getting those errors ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception, from your server's log file.

Comment: the whole stake is :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because the return value of "fr.dsidiff.pdf.client.model.response.PdfConvertAndSignResponse.getData()" is null

From server i do have nothing at all. Otherwise concerning 413, it's just an html page